# Data structures - equivalence classes

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to match $(\log_2n)^5$ to an equivalence class.
Any ideas? thought maybe about $n^5$ but thant it matches only as big O.

Comment: It certainly is far less than $n^5$. The power of any logarithm grows slower than any polynomial, so $(\log_2 n)^5 \in O(n)$, or more generally $O(n^{\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Without knowing the set of equivalence classes you are using then this is not possible to answer. I would personally say it is $\Theta(\log(n)^5)$. It definitely isn't $\Theta(\log(n))$, nor $\Theta(n^{\epsilon}\log(n))$, nor $\Theta(n^5)$, so you should probably give at least a reference to the equivalence classes you may use.

Comment: Well, for $b>0$ we'll have $(\log_2n)^5=\Theta((\log_bn)^5)$, for what it's worth.